# Parsing php with jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I`m trying to parse date in PHP. I copy part of several examples but it is not working.
What I am trying to do is :
I have a PHP file that receives a variable 'parttype' and runs a query.

```
<?php

$parttype = $_POST['parttype'];
 echo "$parttype";              

$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn , "shop") or die ("db will not open");

$query = "SELECT * from parts where parttype='$parttype'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

echo '<table border="1" align ="center"><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>InStock</th><th>Description</th><th>SUpplier</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Remove</th></tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr><form action='ppcomppartout.php' method='post'><td><input type='hidden' name='partid' value='$row[0]'>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . "</td><td>" . $row[2] . "</td><td>" . $row[3] . "</td><td>" . $row[5] . "</td><td>" . $row[6] . "</td>
  <td><input type='text' name='qtty' placeholder='0'></td><td>Buy <input type='submit'></td>
  </form></tr>";
  }  

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);                                       

 ?>
```

Then in the index.php I have a `function get()` that posts the variable to data.php
and another function that is not working - `function parse(data)`. I eventually insert a button to get some results, but I wanted the results to come up as soon as I change the values on the select box.

```
 <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function get() {
    $.post("data.php", {parttype: form.parttype.value },
    function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output).show();
    });
    }


function parse(data){
 $('#output').append('<select>');

 $("select").on("change", function(evt) 
        {
          line_record( $("select option:selected").index(),data)
        });

}       

 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <form name="form">

     <select name="parttype" style="width: 117px">
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($con , "shop") or die ("db will not open");

$query = "SELECT distinct parttype from parts";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid query");

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option value=\"" . $rows[0] . "\">" . $rows[0] . "   </option>";
}
echo "</select>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
     </select>

<!--<input type="submit" value="OK!!"/>-->
 </form>
<!--<input type="text" name="parttype">-->

<!--<input type="button" value="Get" onClick="get();" >-->
<input type="submit" value="Get" onClick="get();" >

 </form> 

  <div id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can some one help with this?? What I am doing wrong ??

Comment: Well, your English may not be good, but at least you're using SQLi feaures.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what the problem is exactly, but you should take it step by step.

The first problem you will encounter is probably when you call your `get()` function on page load. The data you are sending to your php script is:

```
{parttype: form.parttype.value }
```

where `form.parttype.value` seems to be undefined. If you want to send the values of your form, you can change that to:

```
$("form").serialize()
```

You should also check your html source as there seem to be multiple closing `form` tags.

**Note:** You are dumping your `$_POST` variable in your sql query without any validation or escaping. You should really switch to prepared statements as your code is vulnerable to sql injection.